# StrikeThrough effect on a TextBlock

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, microsoft-metro, windows-store-apps

In a Windows Store App, is there any way to apply a StrikeThrough effect on a TextBlock's content? If there isn't, a RichTextBlock or any similar controls would do. It doesn't matter if it's through XAML or programmatically (C#), but I'd prefer through XAML so it would show in the designer.

I found this among Microsoft's documentation, but I don't know how to use it:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.text.itextcharacterformat.strikethrough.aspx

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Windows Store apps have their own control namespace (System.Ui.Xaml.Controls).  You'll see that the TextBlock for Windows Store apps doesn't have a TextDecoration property: [TextBlock documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.textblock.aspx).

The "full" .Net 4.5 TextBlock does have a TextDecoration property:[.Net 4.5 WPF TextBlock Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textblock.aspx).

You can do this in a "hacky" way like so:

```
    <Grid Height="30">
        <TextBlock Text="This is a test" FontSize="22" Height="34" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Foreground="White"   />
        <Line Stretch="Fill" Stroke="white" StrokeThickness="2 " X1="1" Width="120" VerticalAlignment="Center"  HorizontalAlignment="Center"   />
    </Grid>
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I added a `Margin="0,10,0,0"` and the line appears right through the text. Also removed the `HorizontalAlignment` and `Width` properties to make it fill the parent cell and strike through the entire text.

Answer (score 3):

It seems it isn't possible after all:

> "we will not able to include the TextDecoration class for the final
>   realese of the XAML framework for Windows 8.  This means that you will
>   not be able to use the strikethrough feature, but you will still be
>   able to underline text via the Underline class."

(http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-CA/winappswithcsharp/thread/cba0c363-60da-4e4e-9fc1-93f7c3658aff)

However, Microsoft is working on this:

> "This is a known limitation in XAML text story in the Windows 8
>   developer preview. On the bright side this is an area with planned
>   improvements happening soon hereafter and we expect to resolve this
>   issue."

(http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithcsharp/thread/d5362fe2-48f6-448d-92ae-25216345c46d)

Answer (score 0):

Simply try this :

```
<TextBlock>TextBlock with <Span TextDecorations="Strikethrough">Strike through sample</Span></TextBlock>
```

Here is the documentation about [TextDecorations.Strikethrough](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.textdecorations.strikethrough?view=windowsdesktop-7.0) property