# How to strike out the texts in Paragraph?

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml, strikethrough, richtextblock

I am developing an app for Windows 8.1

The App parses HTML codes, and displays the contents on RichTextBlock.

Anyway, I'm trying to display some texts with 'StrikeThrough' line. like shown below.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qLAPk.png]

I searched through the web, but I just found that there is no native way to do that on WIndows 8.1

I tried the solution on '[StrikeThrough effect on a TextBlock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12772308/strikethrough-effect-on-a-textblock)', but I don't think this solution can display some texts which exceed the width of RichTextBlock (I need those texts to be displayed in new line.)

Also, I don't display texts on TextBlock directly,

In my app, texts are displayed like below

```
RichTextBlock - Paragraph - Run (Texts)
```

Is there any good solution for this problem? 
(The easiest way to display 'Strikeout texts' on RichTextBlock)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think those people who reviewed my question did not even read this thread.
I already mentioned the link to a similar question, but the answer in that thread didn't give a right solution.
Anyway, some reviewers decided this thread as a duplicate question and gave me the link which I mentioned above.

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your text

```
TextBlock1.TextDecorations = TextDecorations.Strikethrough;
```